# Add a View on top of a ListView and move everything when scrolling down?

Tags: android, listview

I want to add a View op top of a list view (let's call it the header). When the user scrolls down I want all the content to move up (including the header). However right now when the user scrolls the header stays fixed on top (as in "position:fixed" on css) instead of scrolling with the rest of the content.

How can I let the user scroll everything instead of just the contents of the ListView?

This is what my layout looks like now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="?attr/color2">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    style="@style/header"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_setup"
    android:text="@string/fragment_contacts"/>


<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false">

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**my_layout_header.xml**

This is the XML layout of your list's header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_setup"
  android:text="@string/fragment_contacts" />
```

**my_layout.xml**

This is the main layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
  android:fastScrollEnabled="false" />
```

**The code**

Now you need to inflate the header layout XML into a `View` and set it as a header view to your `ListView`. The following snippet can be used inside an `Activity.onCreate(Bundle)`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

View header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.my_layout, null);
// where "this" is a context / activity...

ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
list.addHeaderView(header, null, false); // header will not be clickable
// ... whatever else you need to do AFTER you set a header (a bug before KITKAT) ...
```